# dataset.assign_attrs() example?

Tags: python-xarray

I just started using xarray today and so far am very impressed by how easy it is to use.  I do have one question regarding the assign_attrs() function for a dataset.

I have a dataset that I am creating from a pandas dataframe.  I am trying to assign metadata attributes to it after it has been created, however I don't seem to get anything when i look at ds.attrs or ds.attrs.items() after running the script.

I am passing it a dictionary, but perhaps I am not doing it correctly? I have tried a variety of methods of passing the dict, but nothing seems to work.  Any help or examples would be appreciated.  example code and output follows:

IN:

```
df = pd.read_csv(readstr)
md = pr.plot_results.get_metadata(fp)

refdata = {'refLat': md['refLat'], 
           'refLon': md['refLon'], 
           'refAlt': md['refAlt'],
               'fw': md['FWversion']}

for k,v in refdata.items():
   print(k, v, "refdata kv")

ds = xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)
ds.assign_attrs(refdata)


print(ds.attrs, 'attributes')
print(ds.attrs.items(), 'items')
print(ds.attrs['refLon'])
```

OUT:

```
python_gnss_plot git:master ❯ ./start_plots.py                              
✹ ✭

refLat 37.77101988 refdata kv
refLon -122.40315123 refdata kv
refAlt -5.6120 refdata kv
fw v140-develop-2018060121-7 refdata kv
OrderedDict() attributes
odict_items([]) items
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Fil
  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/
lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", 
line 1699, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "./start_plots.py", line 109, in execute_calc
    print(ds.attrs['refLon'])
KeyError: 'refLon'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assign_attrs` returns a *new* `xarray.Dataset` with the given attributes. It's designed to facilitate chained operations on xarray objects that don't mutate existing objects.

If you want to update the attributes of a Dataset inplace, just assign to `ds.attrs` directly, or use `ds.attrs.update()`, e.g.,

```
ds.attrs = refdata
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response and explanation.  Works beautifully now.